# How to Detect and Convert URL images and Videos from Plain Text URL's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, image

Hi i need to detect and convert urls images and video from plain text urls

Html

```
<div id="content-url">
 Hello World<br>
 http://www.goalterest.com/  <br>
 http://www.esotech.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/jquery_logo.png
 http://www.esotech.org/wp-content/uploads
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
var photoRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]).(?:jpg|gif|png)/ig;

  var url_url= $('#content-url').html().match(urlRegex);
var url_photo= $('#content-url').html().match(photoRegex);

  var convert_url='<a href="'+url_url+'">'+url_url+'</a>';
var convert_photo='<img src="'+url_photo+'" width="150" height="150" alt="Nba">';
$('#content-url').append(convert_url);
$('#content-url').append(convert_photo);
```

Here Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/nqVJc/3/

In the demo i get the way to detect and convert to url and photo but the problem ist when ist there multiple urls The Urls are not separated

Comment: Are you trying to replace the link with an image, or append the images and links to the bottom?

Comment: I think that best way ist to replace  the detected url or just hide them after append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not iterating through the matched elements :

```
$.each( url_url, function(i,value){
   var convert_url='<a href="'+url_url[i]+'">'+url_url[i]+'</a>';
   var convert_photo='<img src="'+url_photo[i]+'" width="150" height="150" alt="Nba">';
   $('#content-url').append(convert_url,convert_photo)
});
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FpsxC/)**.

For removing matched urls you need to add this lines before `$.each` :

```
$('#content-url').html( $('#content-url').html().replace(urlRegex,''));

//$.each goes here
```

Comment: That was very helful almost solved all the needs Here ist updated DEMO [link]http://jsfiddle.net/nqVJc/7/[link] Now i only need to hide the plain text urls that was detected

Comment: @RobertMrsic I will update my answer, so you could accept it.

Comment: i accept it already but just a question can i hide also converted photo urls in same way

Comment: @RobertMrsic Yes, just use proper `RegExp`.

Comment: Don't do regex-replaces on innerHTML. You should traverse through text nodes and work with them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex could be improved. [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) offers [URI.withinString()](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#static-withinString) to extract URLs. The Regex used here is [gruber revised](http://rodneyrehm.de/t/url-regex.html#gruber+revised):

```
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/ig
```